# Multipe Ito Integrals

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Im working on a Lemma 10.8 in the Book "Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations by Kloeden And Platen" I have been stuck on one point. Can somebody help me to understand how he moved to second last and the last line in equation (8.3) in the second picture that I have added. Moreover Im adding the picture for Lemma 5.7.3 as well which has been used in the proof.Kindly help me in this regard
Thanks in anticipation.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/841031/lemma-on-multiple-ito-integrals

Comment: Yes that was also uploaded by me but kept on hold cause of less information. But this time I have tried to provide all the info needed for this.

Comment: Still, it is rather hard to read.

Comment: I reckon now it is readable. Kindly help me if you can.

Comment: New account+duplicate question+still no personal input? Nice combo...